# Inverse Identity + Constant Matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I need to invert a square symmetric matrix $$ C = c\, I+cs\, B    $$
Where: (1) $B$ is a constant matrix of 1 for each entry. (2) $c$ and cs are just positive real numbers. (3) $I$ is the identity.

However, the $\det(B) = 0$ and $B$ by itself does not have an inverse, but I am sure that C must have one.

Problem: What is $C^{-1}$ in terms of $cs, c$?

Comment: $B=(b_{ij})$, $C=(c_{ij})$, so $C=(c\delta_{ij}+c_sb_{ij})$, where $\delta_{xy}$ is the Kronecker symbol. Try to develop the determinant here, usign the fact that $b_{ij}=\sum_{h\neq i}b_{hj},\ \forall j$

Comment: Thanks, but im not sure what to do with the determinant bcs the inverse is adjoint matrix/det and the adjoint is hard to compute (or im not familiar with it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate $B^2$, calculate $C\cdot (aI+bB)$, determine the values of $a$ and $b$ that give the identity matrix.

Comment: Thank you. The answer is -cs/(c*(c+cs*N)) B  +1/a *I

Comment: That is correct (if you replace a with c).

Comment: Thanks, by the way, how did you know the form of the inverse had to have the sum of the SAME matricies?

Comment: @AimForClarity First of all, I have seen the matrix with only 1s in other problems before, so its properties are already at the back of my head. In general, you can express any inverse matrix as polynomial in the matrix (just multiply the minimal polynomial by the inverse), so I am already motivated to look at this. To find the minimal polynomial directly, it is clearly useful to calculate $B^2$ and the identity $B^2=nB$ tells me that the minimal polynomial for $I+B$ must have degree 2, so the expression for the inverse (if it exists) must have degree 1 in $B$.

Comment: However, I would be quite impressed if someone found this without ever having seen something similar.

Comment: Very neat, it is good to think of the expansion as you suggest

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Neumann series which is the inverse, if it converges:
$$A^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(I-A)^k\qquad\text{(if convergent)}$$

Now we apply this to $\frac1c C = I + \frac{c_s}c B$ and get using $B^k = n^{k-1} B$ for $k>0$ (since $B^2=nB$) the following
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(I - \frac1c C\right)^k
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{c_s}c\right)^k B^k \\
&= \frac1n\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{c_s n}c\right)^k\right) B + I\\
&= \frac1n\left(\frac1{1+\frac{c_s n}c} - 1\right) B + I\\
&= \frac{-c_s}{c + c_s n}B + I = \left(\frac1c C\right)^{-1},
\end{align*}
at least if $\left|\frac{c_s n}c\right| < 1$. From this it follows
$$ C^{-1} = \frac{-c_s}{c(c+c_sn)}B + \frac1c I. \tag{*}$$

Now we can see that
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{-c_s}{c(c+c_sn)}B + \frac1c I\right)\left(cI + c_s B\right)
&= \frac{-c_s}{c+c_sn}B + \frac{-c_s^2}{c(c+c_sn)}B^2 + I + \frac{c_s}{c}B\\
&= \left(\frac{-c_s}{c+c_sn} + \frac{-n c_s^2}{c(c+c_sn)} + \frac{c_s}{c}\right)B + I \\
&= \frac{-c c_s + -n c_s^2 + c_s(c+c_sn)}{c(c+c_sn)}B + I\\
&= I \\
\end{align}
independent of $\frac{c_s n}c$, as long as $c(c+c_sn)\neq 0$. So (*) holds if $c\neq0$ and $c_s\neq -\frac cn$.